# Forground and background Chat issue with websocket and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

I've created a chat system with socket functionality, managing to store and display messages. Yet, I'm struggling to receive messages when not on the chat page or when the app is terminated. I attempted solutions like provider state management and WorkManager but encountered no success. My goal is to receive messages even in scenarios where I'm not actively on the chat page or when the app is terminated.

Comment: You can implement FCM to achieve this functionality; relying on background processes isn't advisable, as Android and iOS have limitations on running applications continuously in the background.

Comment: how do i go about that

do i just save the messages directly from the push notification when i implement the FCM

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`flutter_background_service`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) to be able to keep the connection open with the server while the app is in background or terminated.